# python: How to organize methods in a class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have the situation in which I instantiate a class that has long calculations to calculate several attributes.
The following is an example.

```
class Father():
    def __init__(self, fathername, age):
        self.fathername = fathername
        self.age = age
        self.initials =  self.initials()
        self.initials2 =  self.initials2()
        self.salary = self.salary(self.age)
    
    # using internal methods    
    def initials(self):
        '''
        long calculation
        '''
        return self.fathername[0:1]
    
    def initials2(self):
        '''
        long calculation based on initials1 and on many previously calculated attributes
        '''
        return self.initials.upper()
    
    
    @staticmethod
    def salary(age):
        '''
        long calculation
        '''
        result = age*1000
        return result
```

the question is what o the follwing is the way to go.
a) no methods at all,all the code together and when the attributes are calculated simply set them

```
# peseudocode:
self.attribute = XX
# further calculations
self.attribute2 = YY
```

b) As in the example code above. Using internal methods to separate functionalities. Including class methods that return a value that is passed to the corresponding attribute. The advantage is that it is possible to nicely arrange all the attributes in **init** gives a nice overview

c) using static methods. Which I think is not the way to go because they are never going to be called from outside the class

d) using @property. which I think is not the way to go since that would mean every time an attribute is called the methods rerun.

I would go for option b, but somehow I have the feeling is not very pythonic.

Which other way would code that class otherwise assuming the code in the methods is quite long?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think option `b` is the best one for the same reasons you already mentioned. However, if your calculations are very long, you could try to see if there are repeated operations between the various methods. This way you could create ad hoc functions to perform those operations, thus reducing the calculations of the others. It is not recommended to have very long methods, as they are difficult to write correctly, difficult to understand and difficult to test.

Comment: there is nothing repeated. a few independent methods call different APIs manipulate data extract data and combine data in order to furhter call other APIs and at the end give back  some data